# IFF statement reworded, which is equivalent?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-explanation

The problem is given as:

> Prove that a subset {**u**<sub>1</sub>, . . ,**u**<sub>p</sub>} in V
>   is linearly independent if and only if the set of coordinate vectors
>   {[**u**<sub>1</sub>]<sub>B</sub>, . . , [**u**<sub>p</sub>]<sub>B</sub>} is linearly
>   independent in ℝ<sup>n</sup>.

The problem was reworded as (note it's no longer an IFF):

> Prove if {**u**<sub>1</sub>, . . ,**u**<sub>p</sub>} in V is linearly
>   independent, then {[**u**<sub>1</sub>]<sub>B</sub>, . . , [**u**<sub>p</sub>]<sub>B</sub>} is
>   linearly independent in ℝ<sup>n</sup>.

I'm having a hard time seeing if the reworded problem is equivalent to the original problem going forwards or backwards, since the original problem is an IFF.

If I were to prove the reworded problem by contrapositive by supposing one of the sets are linearly dependent, which set do I start with being dependent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rewording is one direction of the original biconditional.  The original statement implies the rewording but it is not obvious that the new statement implies the original.  In this case you can derive the original so they are equivalent in the sense of both being true.

If you want to prove the rewording by using the contrapositive, you assume the set {[**u**<sub>1</sub>]<sub>B</sub>, . . , [**u**<sub>p</sub>]<sub>B</sub>} is dependent and show the other one is.

Comment: The reworded form is my teacher's way of going forward for the original IFF statement. I'm seeing the way of going forward is if the set of coordinate vectors are independent, then the subset in V is independent. The other way is if the subset is independent, then the set of coordinate vectors is independent. Which doesn't match my teacher's way. I must be thinking it wrong. Can you please clarify if the reworded statement is equivalent to the original going forwards or backwards?

Comment: When you say A if and only if B, the if part would be $B \implies A$ and the only if part would be $A \implies B$ so the reworded version is the only if part.  If you say it carefully, if A then B is the same as A only if B.